# Trying to define my own time type in PHP

Tags: php, time, format

So I am trying to define a time type and I am not quite sure how to do it. The answers I find online give examples of defining a time type with the current time (i.e **date("h:i:sa")**) however I am trying to define a hard coded version.The format I want is **(HH:mm:ss) (hour:minutes:seconds)** The reason why I need the variable to be declared as time type is so that they can be used later on to be compared.

```
<?php 
$my_time = '10:00:00';
$your_time = '11:00:00';
if($my_time > $your_time){
echo "You have less time";
}
?>
```

Comment: The code is just an example to give an idea of what i'm trying to do, I just want to define my own time variable to which it will be used for comparison with another time object at a later stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP DateTime Class is what you need.

```
//instantiate a DateTime Object      
$time = new DateTime();

//Use the DateTime obj to create two new DateTime objects
$yourTime = $time->createFromFormat('h:i:s', '12:30:30'); //third param here can define tz
$theirTime = $time->createFromFormat('h:i:s', '12:10:15');

//Use diff() to return a DateInterval
$dateInterval = $yourTime->diff($theirTime);

//Format the DateInterval as a string
$differenceBetweenYoursAndTheirs = $dateInterval->format('%h:%i:%s');

//Do something with your interval
echo "The difference between {$yourTime->format('h:i:s')} and {$theirTime->format('h:i:s')} is $differenceBetweenYoursAndTheirs";
```

Comment: @hankypanky wins the race

Comment: Only seeing this now, This is also very useful thank you. I have a better understanding of the DateTime Object

Answer (score 3):

Use **[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)** to create proper objects, then you can use standard comparison operators.

```
$my_time   = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '10:00:00');
$your_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '11:00:00');
var_dump($my_time > $your_time);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/542110)**